# Are operators in C implemented as functions like C++?

Tags: c++, c, function, operator-overloading, operators

I was reading a tutorial on operator overloading in C++ when I saw this:

> In C++, operators are implemented as functions. By using function overloading on the operator functions, you can define your own versions of the operators that work with different data types.
>
> The compiler comes with a built-in version of the plus operator (+) for integer operands -- this function adds integers x and y together and returns an integer result.

Are operators in C also implemented as functions? If not, how are operators implemented in C?

Could it also be that operators being implemented as functions for POD types is something that only certain compilers do?

Comment: The other option is that the tutorial is wrong.

Comment: I c these will be simply translated to assembly code.

Comment: same as in C++ @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @molbdnilo It's possible but this is a very trusted tutorial that emphasizes how to write proper C++. It's learncpp.com

Comment: Operators in C are implemented by whatever code the compiler chooses to emit.  Usually each operator translates to a single instruction (e.g. `+` → `ADD`), but sometimes there may be a function call involved, such as for wide-word division on processors with limited support.  Operators in C++ are also implemented this way for built-in ("POD") types; it's only for user-defined types that operators are implemented as functions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I thought C and C++ compilers translate source code to machine code? Is it first translated to assembly and then to machine code?

Comment: @user21290559 learncpp.com is almost as rubbish as the rest of the rubbish. There's no online C++ tutorial that's worth its price.

Comment: @user21290559 Whether a compiler emits assembly language which is translated to machine language as a second step, or emits machine language directly, is an implementation detail.  Some compilers do it one way, some the other.  (And the first C++ compiler emitted C code which was then compiled by a C compiler.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Have you been on learncpp.com? It literally covers the majority of what is necessary to learn in C++ while teaching you the proper guidelines. I'm not saying that it is the best, but it's definitely much better than all other free tutorials out there.

Comment: @molbdnilo If you could provide facts about why the content on learncpp.com is rubbish, then could you please point me to another free resource that is better? (And many people don't have access to money to pay for a paid tutorial).

Comment: @user21290559 I would suggest buying a decent C++ book. Do not learn from the internet

Comment: You can learn worthwhile things even from a crappy tutorial, it's quoting it as an authority that you should avoid. Specifically the piece you quoted is oversimplified to the point of being wrong.

Comment: @teapot418 Thank you, I admit I was a bit hasty in defending the website. But people calling it rubbish while not providing any facts is something negative. I will make sure to keep a skeptical eye when learning from a tutorial and will try to confirm it's validity. And I only showed a portion of the text from the tutorial. I will update the answer.

Comment: @user21290559 If you want to see what code your compiler emits, why not *look at it*?  For example, `gcc` has a `-S` options that caused it to produce a `.s` file, which contains the assembly code for your source file.  Then you can look at it and answer your own question for your particular platform.

Comment: A non-rubbish tutorial (although I'm biased in my opinion of it) is https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/cclass.html .

Comment: @TomKarzes I did not know that. I am on Windows using mingw. Does that change anything?

Comment: The only free sources of good C++ materials are piracy and shoplifting. If you can afford it, any used decent book from the last couple of decades is much better than what you find "enthusiasts" writing about online.(And that the site got this extremely fundamental thing wrong should be all the evidence of rubbishosity you need.)

Comment: @molbdnilo The C++ of today is not the C++ of two or even one decade ago. There were no smart pointers back then, less advanced templates, utf8 literals, inline variables and much more. Besides, mistakes can be made. I advise that you look at this tutorial. And not a 2 minute glance but rather a half hour look if you are serious about being right about this argument.

Comment: @user21290559 I'm not familiar with mingw, but I think it supports the -S option.  Did you try it?  You can always look at the man page.

Comment: @TomKarzes I tried it and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The questions is clear, comments indicate that readers understand it well (except for a somewhat crabbed comment by one of the close voters), and there's an accepted (although somewhat simplistic) answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question has been the victim of overly-aggressive close voting, so I can't post an answer. If I could I would point out that having a function for basic operations on built-in types is a reasonable mental model. It makes it much easier to grasp how operator overloading works: it's just like function overloading. And, of course, the "as if" rule means that it doesn't have to actually be implemented that way.

Comment: @PeteBecker I look forward to the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always found it easier to think about operator overloading as being **exactly** the same as function overloading: the compiler uses the types of the arguments to choose the appropriate overload. For ordinary functions that's straightforward: just look at all the functions with the appropriate name that are in scope, and choose the best match.

For operator overloading its just as easy, provided you're willing to forget the detail that the compiler itself knows about all those operators. When I see code that uses the `+` operator I look at the argument types and mentally apply the rules for choosing the best overload. For a really simple example:

```
struct S {
};
int operator+(S s1, S s2) { return 42; }

S s;
int x1 = 1 + 1; // uses "builtin" operator+
int x2 = s + s; // uses user-defined operator+
```

So, that's easy; it doesn't really matter how you think about what underlies those two `+` operators. But let's make it a bit more tricky:

```
struct T {
    operator S() const { return S(); }
};

S s;
T t;
int x3 = s + t;
```

Now what? Since there's an `S` involved in the sum, the compiler looks for `+` operators that take an `S`, and it finds the one we defined earlier. And because `T` can be converted to an `S`, it can convert the `t` to an `S` object and then use `operator+(S, S)`. Easy enough, right?

Now, instead of having a conversion to `S`, let's have a conversion to `int`:

```
struct U {
    operator int() { return 42; }
};
```

and let's try the analogous code:

```
int i = 1;
U u;

int x4 = i + u;
```

Having just done the previous example, it's easy to see the analogy for the analysis here: a `U` can be converted to an `int`, so the compiler can convert `u` to an `int` object and then use `operator+(int, int)`.

To me that's much simpler than having two categories, builtin types and user-defined types, and two disjoint notions of operators and how to analyze them.

So, I think of builtin operators as if they were user-defined operators in order to sort out which overload should be called.

Now, that doesn't mean that the compiler in fact uses function calls for these builtin operators. That could be inefficient; in fact, compilers these days typically generate the code to add two numbers directly, typically as a couple of machine instructions. But that's not required; a conforming implementation could actually have a function to add two `int` values and call that when it sees something like `1 + 1`. And sometimes that makes sense. Consider an 8-bit processor and the code for adding two `long long` values. Yes, it could be done inline. But implementing an 8-byte addition in a function and calling it whenever it's needed could result in smaller code; for an embedded system that can be important.

The point here is that for understanding what an expression means, it doesn't matter whether `+` produces a function call or some inline code. The **meaning** of the code doesn't depend on how it's implemented.

So, to get back to the original question: typically operators for builtin types are not implemented as functions in C or in C++, although it's legal to do it that way. But **thinking of them** as functions means you don't have to shift gears when you're looking at overloaded operators. So, the tutorial's assertion that "In C++, operators are implemented as functions" isn't actually correct. But it's a useful mental model for thinking about operators in C++.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

> In C++, operators are implemented as functions

Is wrong.

Operators for fundamental types are predefined in C and C++.

But in C++ you may overload operators as functions for user-defined types.

In C there is absent such a possibility.